# Getting Laravel Session value in in blade file with JQuery

Tags: jquery, laravel

I am assigning a value to a session in a controller after which redirects to a blade file which, on jquery checking the session value, is supposed to submit a form in the blade file. I am trying to use this jquery script to check the session value but it is not working

```
<script>
   jQuery( document ).ready( function () {
       var name= "{{ Session::get('response')  }}"
       if(name == 'success')
       {
           jQuery("#info_form").submit();   
       }
     });
</script>
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Have you checked what the value of `name` actually is?

Comment: Try to use {!!  !!} instead of {{ }}   ===> {!! Session::get('response') !!} instead of  {{ Session::get('response')  }}

Comment: you can use session helper instead ```{{ session('response') }}```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using Flash Data.

They are stored in session as well, but their role is to just show it once.
Check the docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/session#flash-data)

```
$request->session()->flash('status', 'Task was successful!');
```

and in blade I think you use it with @flash